# Sync Error While updating existing Item (when QB closing date is set)

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are getting below sync error on Item Update (only if we have set the closing date for QuickBooks company file) otherwise Item update successfully.

Sync Error:- "An attempt was made to modify the post account(s) for ItemInventory list. This modification would affect the existing transactions of the company. If you are sure you really want to do this, please ask a user with Admin privileges to remove the password for the closing date (this setting is in the Accounting Company Preferences), then try again."

```
'Searching existing Item
Dim qbItemSearch As New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item()
qbItemSearch.Id = New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() With { .idDomain = idDomainEnum.NG, .Value = "123456" }

Dim qbItem As Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item = Nothing
qbItem = DataServices.FindById(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item)(qbItemSearch)

'Updating some properties of the Item
qbItem.Name = "new name"
qbItem.Desc = "new desc"
qbItem.PurchaseCost = newPurchase...
qbItem.UnitPrice = newUnitPrice...

Dim itemResponse = DataServices.Update(qbUpdateItem)
```

It works fine if we remove the company closing date from QuickBooks. 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal QuickBooks functionality. Once the books are closed for the year, you don't make changes to the financials. Once completed, you re-open and continue business as usual.